# Jquery - Checkbox staying checked - simple filter system

Tags: jquery, html, forms, filter, checkbox

I am building a very simple filter system where I want to have html checkboxes that can show and hide items of particular categories.

The problem is that the checkboxes stay checked no matter what.

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jmnwr/

HTML:

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="categorya" id="filter-categorya" /><label for="filter-categorya">Category A</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="categoryb" id="filter-categoryb" /><label for="filter-categoryb">Category B</label></li>
</ul>

<div class="categorya"></div>
<div class="categorya"></div>
<div class="categorya"></div>
<div class="categorya"></div>
<div class="categoryb"></div>
<div class="categoryb"></div>
<div class="categoryb"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#filter-categorya").toggle(
function() {
    $('.categorya').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.2);
    $('#filter-categorya').removeAttr('checked');
}, function() {
    $('.categorya').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    $('#filter-categorya').attr('checked', 'checked');
});

$("#filter-categoryb").toggle(
function() {
    $('.categoryb').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.2);
    $('#filter-categoryb').removeAttr('checked');
}, function() {
    $('.categoryb').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    $('#filter-categoryb').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

I have seen two posts regarding this topic but not sure if they are entirely related or why my code in particular is not working. I've also tried using the preventdefault function but it didn't do anything:

[Unable to control checkbox checked status - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307272/unable-to-control-checkbox-checked-status-jquery)
[Why won't .attr('checked','checked') set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596854/why-wont-attrchecked-checked-set)

Any help always appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the toggle method correctly, the signatures look weird to me!

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with this note: "The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event". Wasn't aware that would prevent default state change actions, but perhaps it does. I would just use "change" instead of toggle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's being blocked by `preventDefault()`. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/q8bAE/5/ You can see that the 2nd checkbox functions normally, while the first remains in its initial state when clicked.

It appears that `preventDefault()` causes checkbox change actions to be stopped... which I didn't know until right now! The docs for `toggle()` say "the implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event"

Comment: +1 to you, sir.  I was unaware that toggle() called preventDefault!

Answer (score 2):

Im not totally sure why you get the error when doing it that way, but changing the code to use 'change' fixes it..

http://jsfiddle.net/Jmnwr/13/

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another solution, dynamically grabbing the category from the checkbox value.

http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/Jmnwr/17/

Comment: Thanks! Definitely useful to grab the category dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I never liked using `removeAttr` with `checked`... try leaving that out ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/Jmnwr/25/)). It's even less code.

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle()` is intended to show/hide the element in question.

Here's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pBKbz/