# jQuery filtering with And and Or statements

Tags: jquery, filtering

I'm having to build a complex filtering system for a list of products. Below is the basic structure of the product list:

```
<ul id="prod-list">
    <li class="item type-brochure lang-english">Brochure: English</li>
    <li class="item type-folder lang-english lang-french">Folder: English, French</li>
    <li class="item type-bulletin lang-english">Bulletin: English</li>
    <li class="item type-folder lang-english lang-french">Folder: English, French</li>
    <li class="item type-folder lang-english">folder: English</li>
    <li class="item type-brochure lang-english lang-spanish">Brochure: English, Spanish</li>
    <li class="item type-brochure lang-english">Brochure: English</li>
    <li class="item type-folder lang-english">Folder: English</li>
    <li class="item type-bulletin lang-english">Bulletin: English</li>
</ul>
```

I then have checkboxes for each type and language filter:

```
<p><strong>Filter by Type:</strong></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="type-brochure" /> <label for="type-brochure">Brochure</label></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="type-folder" /> <label for="type-folder">Folder</label></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="type-bulletin" /> <label for="type-bulletin">Bulletin</label></p>
...
<p><strong>Filter by Language:</strong></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="lang-english" /> <label for="lang-english">English</label></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="lang-spanish" /> <label for="lang-spanish">Spanish</label></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="lang-french" /> <label for="lang-french">French</label></p>
...
```

As you can see, each item has a type and then a language. *An item can have multiple types and languages.*

Basically, I need the checkboxes for the types to act as an **OR** statement (If the user checks the checkboxes for Brochure and Folder, it will list all Brochures **and** Folders, then hide all others).

I then need the checkboxes for the languages to act as an **AND** statement (If the user checks the checkboxes for English and French, it will only show the items that are both English **AND** French, then hide all others).

I took a look at other questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796472/filtering-with-checkboxes-using-jquery), but I'm not sure how to get something like that to work with two different filtering methods. The filters need to work together, such that if a user checks Brochure, English, French, it will only show Brochures that are both English and French.

If anyone would have some advice on how to accomplish this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by:

- starting with an empty jQuery object,
- then iterating over the checked `type-` boxes and calling [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to accumulate the OR-filtered elements,
- then iterating over the checked `lang-` boxes and calling [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the element set.

Something like:

```
function updateItems()
{
    var $matched;
    var $checkedTypeBoxes = $("input[type='checkbox'][id^='type-']:checked");
    if (!$checkedTypeBoxes.length) {
        $matched = $("#prod-list .item");
    } else {
        $matched = $();
        $checkedTypeBoxes.each(function() {
            // Add items of checked type.
            $matched = $matched.add("#prod-list .item." + this.id);
        });
    }
    $("input[type='checkbox'][id^='lang-']:checked").each(function() {
        // Filter out items that don't expose checked language.
        $matched = $matched.filter("." + this.id);
    });

    $("#prod-list .item").hide();
    $matched.show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    updateItems();
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        updateItems();
    });
});
```

You can test this solution in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dqxA/2/).

Comment: This also works great, but I would like the languages to be filterable by themselves (without having to select a type). So if the user just checks French, it will show everything that is French, regardless of type.

Comment: @scferg5, that is indeed possible, answer and fiddle updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to add a class to your inputs.  For this example, I added 'type-specific' and 'language-specific' to the appropriate inputs.  Here's my not optimized, but readable code.

```
$(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        $('#prod-list li').hide();
        var languages = '';
        $('.language-specific:checked').each(function(){
            languages += '.' + $(this).attr('id');
        });
        if($('.type-specific:checked').length > 0){
            $('.type-specific:checked').each(function(){
                $(languages+'.'+$(this).attr('id')).show();
                console.log(languages+'.'+ $(this).attr('id'));
            });
        } else {
            $(languages).show();
        }
    });
});
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c2wuR/7/) is a fiddle example.  All of the logic is handled with the jquery selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the javascript required to do the filtering.

```
$(':checkbox').change(FindFilters);

function FindFilters() {
    var filterArray = [];
    //which checkboxes are checked?
    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.prop('checked')) {
            filterArray.push($this.prop('id'));
        }
    });

    console.log(filterArray);
    FilterList(filterArray);
}
function containsAll(needles, haystack){ 
    for(var i = 0 , len = needles.length; i < len; i++){
        if($.inArray(needles[i], haystack) == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function FilterList(filters) {
    if (filters.length > 0) {
        $('#prod-list li').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                attributes = $this.prop('class').split(' ');

            if (containsAll(filters,attributes)) {
                $this.slideDown();
            } else {
                $this.slideUp();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#prod-list li').slideDown();
    }
}
```

and here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/nxTPN/

Comment: That works great, except that if you select two types, it's supposed to show both of them (it needs to be an OR statement instead of an AND, but only for the types).

Comment: yes, i apologize. I misread your conditions. I'll fix it real quick.