# How to make my checkbox filter work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, checkbox

I have a functioning product list that is generated by jquery. Now I need it to get filtered by the array attributes: color, size and price. I copied a code from a question that filtered the list items by its classes, and it was working perfectly, but for me, I just can't figure out how to change that to filter by the attributes. I think what needs to be altered is this in the last function `re.test($this.attr("class"))`.

```
<!--HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Teste Vaga Front End</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadList()">

     <header class="menu">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu-lt">
                    <li class="menu-it"><a class="menu-lk logo" href="#">Profite</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-it lst"><a class="menu-lk cart" href="#">Carrinho</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>


    <h2 class="page-title container">Vestidos</h2>

    <div class="content container">
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <h3 class="mobile-btn filter">Filtrar</h3>

            <div id="filters" class="filters-wrapper">
                <div class="fltrs-wppr">
                <section id="colors">
                    <h4>Cores</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="Amarelo"> Amarelo</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="Azul"> Azul</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="Branco"> Branco</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="Cinza"> Cinza</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="Laranja"> Laranja</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="sizes">
                    <h4>Tamanhos</h4>
                    <ul class="fltr-szs-lt">
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">P</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">M</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">G</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">GG</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">U</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">36</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">38</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">40</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">42</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">44</span></li>
                        <li class="fltr-szs-it"><span class="fltr-szs">46</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="prices">
                    <h4>Faixa de Preço</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc0-50"> de R$0 até R$50</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-51-150"> de R$51 até R$150</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-151-300"> de R$151 até R$300</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc301-500"> de R$301 até R$500</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-501-fim"> a partir de R$501</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>

        <section id="products" class="products">
            <header class="products-hdr">
                <h3 class="mobile-btn order">Ordenar</h3>
                <select class="prd-order">
                  <option value="MaisRecentes">Mais Recentes</option>
                  <option value="MaiorPreco">Maior Preço</option>
                  <option value="MenorPreco">Menor Preço</option>
                </select>
            </header>
            <ul id="ProductList" class="product-lt">

            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var productList = {"products": [
    {"image": "img/vestido1.jpg", "description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "amarelo", "size":"P", "price": "390.00"},
    {"image": "img/vestido2.jpg", "description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "cinza", "size":"M", "price": "520.00"},
    {"image": "img/vestido3.jpg", "description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "branco", "size":"G", "price": "42.90"},
    {"image": "img/vestido4.jpg", "description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "branco", "size":"GG", "price": "130.00"},
    {"image": "img/vestido5.jpg", "description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "amarelo", "size":"36", "price": "380.00"},
    {"image": "img/vestido6.jpg", "description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "azul", "size":"38", "price": "44.00"},
    {"image": "img/vestido7.jpg", "description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "cinza", "size":"40", "price": "180.90"},
    {"image": "img/vestido8.jpg", "description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "branco", "size":"42", "price": "560.00"},
    {"image": "img/vestido2.jpg", "description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "cinza", "size":"44", "price": "122.90"}
]
};

//carrega lista sem filtros
function loadList() {

    var list = $("#ProductList");
    var _createELement="";

   $(productList.products).each(function(index){
    _createELement+=
        '<li class="product-it"> <article class="product"> <span class="prd-img-wrapper"> <img class="prd-img" src="' + this.image + '"></span> <h2 class="prd-tit">' + this.description + '</h2> <span class="prd-wrap"><span class="prd-price"><span class="prd-prc"> R$' +  this.price + '</span></br> <span class="prd-par">até 5x de R$' +  parseFloat($(this.price).val()) /5.0 + '</span></span><a class="prd-cart" href="#">Adicionar ao carrinho.</a></span></article></li>'
   });

   $(list).append(_createELement);

}

//filtro
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {

   var re = new RegExp($("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
                          return this.value;
                       }).get().join("|") );
   $("li").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this[re.source!="" && re.test($this.attr("class")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
   });
});
```

Comment: this was the question I got the "filter" code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796472/filtering-with-checkboxes-using-jquery

Comment: did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to modify you render function, to add color attr:

```
$(productList.products).each(function(index){
    _createELement+=
        '<li class="product-it" color="'+ this.color +'"> <article class="product"> <span class="prd-img-wrapper"> <img class="prd-img" src="' + this.image + '"></span> <h2 class="prd-tit">' + this.description + '</h2> <span class="prd-wrap"><span class="prd-price"><span class="prd-prc"> R$' +  this.price + '</span></br> <span class="prd-par">até 5x de R$' +  parseFloat($(this.price).val()) /5.0 + '</span></span><a class="prd-cart" href="#">Adicionar ao carrinho.</a></span></article></li>'
   });
```

Then you can filter your list:

```
function filterBYColor(color) {

  $('.product-it').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this); //your li
     if ($(this).attr('color') == color) {
        $this.show(); //show it if it has the right color
     } else {
        $this.hide(); //hid id it's not
     }

  })
};
```

Try it:

```
filterByColor('azul');
```

**EDIT**
Another function to filter by multiple colors:

```
filterByColors(colors) {

    $('.product-it').each(function(){
         var $this = $(this); //your li
         var color = $this.attr('color'); //it's color

         if (color && colors.indexOf(color) != -1) {
            $this.show(); //show it if it has the right color
         } else {
            $this.hide(); //hid id it's not
         }

      })
}


$(document).on('change', '[name="prices"]', function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    var color = $this.val();
    var colors = [];

    $('[name="prices"]').each(function(){
       if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
           colors.push($(this).attr('color'));
       }
    })

    filterByColors(colors);
})
```

Just add this code to the page and it will work. I havent tested it, but it should.

Comment: I didn't get it, I tried your exact code but nothing happened, and also showed 0 errors... then I tried mixing up with mine to try to get the checkboxes working but also nothing happened :(

Comment: function filterBYColor(color) {
  $('.product-it').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this); //your li
     if ($(this).attr('color') == color) {
        $this.show(); //show it if it has the right color
     } else {
        $this.hide(); //hid if it's not
     }
  })
};

Comment: $("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
   var re = new RegExp($("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
                          return this.value;
                       }).get().join("|") );
   $(".product-it").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this[filterBYColor(re)]();
   });
});

Comment: This was the question I got the code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796472/filtering-with-checkboxes-using-jquery

Comment: I got your code to work by making a button with "onClick="filterBYColor('azul')"". But I still can't make it work for the checkboxes...

Comment: because I need that when you click on two or more checkboxes, it shows all the "li" that fit the colors of the checked checkboxes, not just the last one checked...

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. 
Few values have been changed here like -
`prc0-50 => prc-0-50`. These values are being used by `priceRange` object in JS

```
    <h4>Faixa de Preço</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-0-50"> de R$0 até R$50</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-51-150"> de R$51 até R$150</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-151-300"> de R$151 até R$300</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-301-500"> de R$301 até R$500</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="prices" value="prc-501-fim"> a partir de R$501</li>
    </ul>
```

Please try this JS

```
var productList = {"products": [
{"image": "img/vestido1.jpg", "description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "amarelo", "size":"P", "price": "390.00"},
{"image": "img/vestido2.jpg", "description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "cinza", "size":"M", "price": "520.00"},
{"image": "img/vestido3.jpg", "description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "branco", "size":"G", "price": "42.90"},
{"image": "img/vestido4.jpg", "description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "branco", "size":"GG", "price": "130.00"},
{"image": "img/vestido5.jpg", "description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "amarelo", "size":"36", "price": "380.00"},
{"image": "img/vestido6.jpg", "description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "azul", "size":"38", "price": "44.00"},
{"image": "img/vestido7.jpg", "description": "Bata Bordada", "color": "cinza", "size":"40", "price": "180.90"},
{"image": "img/vestido8.jpg", "description": "Chapéu de Praia com Fivela", "color": "branco", "size":"42", "price": "560.00"},
{"image": "img/vestido2.jpg", "description": "Vestido Texturizado", "color": "cinza", "size":"44", "price": "122.90"}
]
};

var priceRange = {
50: 'prc-0-50',
150: 'prc-51-150',
300: 'prc-151-300',
500: 'prc-301-500',
10000000000: 'prc-501-fim'
}

//carrega lista sem filtros
function loadList() {

var list = $("#ProductList");
var _createELement = "";

$(productList.products).each(function(index) {
    var $this = this;
    var priceRangeClass = '';
    var productColor = (this.color).toLowerCase();
    for (index in priceRange) {
        if (parseFloat($this.price) <= parseFloat(index)) {
            priceRangeClass = priceRange[index];
            break;
        }
    }
    _createELement +=
        '<li class="product-it ' + priceRangeClass + ' ' + productColor + '"> <article class="product"> <span class="prd-img-wrapper"> <img class="prd-img" src="' + this.image + '"></span> <h2 class="prd-tit">' + this.description + '</h2> <span class="prd-wrap"><span class="prd-price"><span class="prd-prc"> R$' + this.price + '</span></br> <span class="prd-par">até 5x de R$' + parseFloat(this.price) / 5.0 + '</span></span><a class="prd-cart" href="#">Adicionar ao carrinho.</a></span></article></li>'
});

$(list).append(_createELement);

//filtro
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {

    var list = $("#ProductList");
    var re = new RegExp($("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return (this.value).toLowerCase();
    }).get().join("|"));
    list.children("li").show();
    list.children("li").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this[re.source != "" && re.test($this.attr("class")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
    });
});

}
```

I believe you can implement for filtering based on size