# Filtering with checkboxes in jQuery but all classes must match criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a page where I filter the classes, my tags, with jQuery.

I found this solution: [Filtering with checkboxes using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796472/filtering-with-checkboxes-using-jquery).

It works but it doesn't give me the result I want. I want when I select category a AND category b that only divs which include the classes a AND b, so it would also show a b c. And when i click all the categories a, b and c, that only a b c shows up.

```js
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    if (!$('.filterOption').is(":checked")) {
        $(".result-box").show();
    } else {
        $(".result-box").hide();
        var results = '.result-box';
        $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            results += "." + $(this).val();
            $(results).show();
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-checkboxes">
  <ul id="filters">
    <li>
      <input class="filterOption" type="checkbox" value="a" id="filter-a" />
      <label for="filter-a">Category A</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="filterOption" type="checkbox" value="b" id="filter-b" />
      <label for="filter-b">Category B</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="filterOption" type="checkbox" value="c" id="filter-c" />
      <label for="filter-c">Category C</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="result-area">
  <div class="result-box a b"  >a b  </div>
  <div class="result-box a c"  >a c  </div>
  <div class="result-box a"    >a    </div>
  <div class="result-box b c"  >b c  </div>
  <div class="result-box c"    >c    </div>
  <div class="result-box a b"  >a b  </div>
  <div class="result-box c"    >a c  </div>
  <div class="result-box b"    >b    </div>
  <div class="result-box a b c">a b c</div>
  <div class="result-box c    ">c    </div>
  <div class="result-box a c"  >a c  </div>
</div>
```

I also put it in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evz4ogwm/3/

Comment: as per your question, when I will select only a, then in this case ab and abc should not be there? right? only a should be there? although its working as it should, on selection of a its showing all the divs which has class a

Comment: One of your values is misleading: `<div class="result-box c"    >a c  </div>` will be shown on just `c` and not on `a and c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a CSS selector that looks like this:

```
.result-box.a.b.c
```

This would apply to any `.result-box` that has all three classes. So you want to join the values of the selected checkboxes with with `.`.

```js
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    if (!$('.filterOption').is(":checked")) {
        $(".result-box").show();
    } else {
        $(".result-box").hide();
        var selector = ".result-box." + $("#filters :checked").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).toArray().join(".");
        $(selector).show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-checkboxes">
  <ul id="filters">
    <li>
      <input class="filterOption" type="checkbox" value="a" id="filter-a" />
      <label for="filter-a">Category A</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="filterOption" type="checkbox" value="b" id="filter-b" />
      <label for="filter-b">Category B</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="filterOption" type="checkbox" value="c" id="filter-c" />
      <label for="filter-c">Category C</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="result-area">
  <div class="result-box a b"  >a b  </div>
  <div class="result-box a c"  >a c  </div>
  <div class="result-box a"    >a    </div>
  <div class="result-box b c"  >b c  </div>
  <div class="result-box c"    >c    </div>
  <div class="result-box a b"  >a b  </div>
  <div class="result-box c"    >a c  </div>
  <div class="result-box b"    >b    </div>
  <div class="result-box a b c">a b c</div>
  <div class="result-box c    ">c    </div>
  <div class="result-box a c"  >a c  </div>
</div>
```